IV for AES-GCM with AAD only
is it required to use a unique IV+key combination with AES-GCM for every authentication operation when there is only AAD data, and nothing to encrypt? Is it safe to use an IV with all zeros?

It's not safe. I'll provide a complete answer later (if someone hasn't yet done). The intuition, however, is that, similarly to the normal case, IV reuse exposes the authentication key, which is sufficient to forge further authentication tags.

"Is it safe to use an IV with all zeros?" - if you use it only once, absolutely :-)
